# Linker errors for multiple defined symbols when defining a static class field

Tags: c++, static, linker-errors, lnk2005

I have a class in which I defined a static integer that I hope will keep track of how many objects of that class get instantiated.

```
class mob {

public:

mob::mob();
mob::mob(std::string, std::string, int, int, int, int, int);
//some other stuff

private:
//some other stuff
static int mob_count;

};
int mob::mob_count = 0;
```

then I define the following constructor:

```
    mob::mob(string name, string wName, int lowR, int highR, int health, int defense, int reward)
{
    nName = name;
    nWeapon.wName = wName;
    nWeapon.wRange.Rlow = lowR;
    nWeapon.wRange.RHigh = highR;
    nHealth = health;
    nArmor = defense;
    xpReward = reward;
    ++mob_count;
}
```

So what am I missing? I think i'm doing everything my text book tells me.

[I get this when compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFFqk.png)

I hope someone can point my mistakes, thank you very much.

EDIT: @linuxuser27 helped me solve my problem, so basically i just moved the

```
 int mob::mob_count = 0;
```

from the class definition, to the class implementation, like so:

### mob.h:

```
class mob {

public:

mob::mob();
mob::mob(std::string, std::string, int, int, int, int, int);
//some other stuff

private:
//some other stuff
static int mob_count;

};
```

### mob.cpp

```
int mob::mob_count = 0;
```

constructor stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are declaring your class in a header file (e.g. `mob.hpp`) and then including the header file in multiple compilation units (i.e. cpp files). Basically this:

#### main.cpp

`#include "mob.hpp"
...`

#### mob.cpp

`#include "mob.hpp"
...`

Remove `int mob::mob_count = 0;` from the header file and put it in the `mob.cpp`.

Comment: Yes i'm including my header files and i know they're properly included because it worked fine before adding this static integer.


Should i define the initialization of  static int mob_count on mob's constructor then?

Comment: So the issue here is that C++ is normally fine with _declaring_ something multiple times as long as you are consistent. However, it is quite finicky about _defining_ a thing multiple times. In this case, leave the declaration in your class as `private`, but move your definition, `int mob::mob_count  = 0;`, to your `mob.cpp` so it will only be defined once.

Comment: You should check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration